# dask.multiprocessing or pandas + multiprocessing.pool: what's the difference?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I'm developing a model for financial purpose. I have the entire S&P500 components inside a folder, stored as many .hdf files. Each .hdf file has its own multi-index (year-week-minute).

**An example of the sequential code (non parallelized):**

```
import os
from classAsset import Asset


def model(current_period, previous_perdiod):
    # do stuff on the current period, based on stats derived from previous_period
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for hdf_file in os.listdir('data_path'):
        asset = Asset(hdf_file)
        for year in asset.data.index.get_level_values(0).unique().values:
            for week in asset.data.loc[year].index.get_level_values(0).unique().values:

                previous_period = asset.data.loc[(start):(end)].Open.values  # start and end are defined in another function
                current_period = asset.data.loc[year, week].Open.values

                model(current_period, previous_period)
```

To speed up the process, I'm using multiprocessing.pool to run the same algorithm on multiple .hdf files at the same time, so I'm quite satisfied with the processing speed (I have a 4c/8t CPU). But now I discovered Dask.

In [Dask documentation 'DataFrame Overview'](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-overview.html#scope) they indicate:

**Trivially parallelizable operations (fast)**:

- Elementwise operations: df.x + df.y, df * df
- Row-wise selections: df[df.x > 0]
- Loc: df.loc[4.0:10.5]  (*this is what interests me the most*)

Also, in [Dask documentation 'Use Cases'](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/use-cases.html#embarrassingly-parallel-computation) they indicate:

> *A programmer has a function that they want to run many times on different inputs. Their function and inputs might use arrays or dataframes internally, but conceptually their problem isn’t a single large array or dataframe.*
>
> *They want to run these functions in parallel on their laptop while they prototype but they also intend to eventually use an in-house cluster. They wrap their function in dask.delayed and let the appropriate dask scheduler parallelize and load balance the work.*

So I'm sure I'm missing something, or probably more than just something. What's the difference between processing many single pandas dataframes with multiprocessing.pool and dask.multiprocessing?

Do you think I should use Dask for my specific case? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no difference.  Dask is doing just what you are doing in your custom code.  It uses pandas and a thread or multiprocessing pool for parallelism.

You might prefer Dask for a few reasons

1. It would figure out how to write the parallel algorithms automatically
2. You may want to scale to a cluster in the future

But if what you have works well for you then I would just stay with that.

Comment: Can you explain me the first point? Or give me a link with a detailed explanation, or an example. Thank you.

Comment: Dask.dataframe provides parallel algorithms for a large subset of the Pandas API (as well as several other APIs).  http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html